Erase charset from java WebClient multiform-data post
We are making a post request in our spring boot application with Java WebClient. The request has MULTIPART_FORM_DATA as MediaType as you can see in the code below:
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> sendMultipartData(PersonRequestDTO personRequest) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parts.add("name", personRequest.getNome());
        parts.add("surname", personRequest.getCognome());
        parts.add("fiscalCode", personRequest.getCodiceFiscale());

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(receiverUrl)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData("name", personRequest.getNome())
                        .with("surname", personRequest.getCognome())
                        .with("fiscalCode", personRequest.getCodiceFiscale()))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class);
    }

Although this is an example of the real request, it is kept as simple as the original one.
Our problem is that when performing the post, a charset UTF-8 is set by default and this seems to be in contrast with some legacy systems which receive the call:
HTTP method: POST
URI: /receive-multipart
Headers:
accept-encoding: gzip
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.9.2.RELEASE
host: localhost:8080
accept: /
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=hw4mxNIYVkHevOoYWQtq-crk1nqxjyD5oez;charset=UTF-8
Parameters:
name: Saverio
surname: Viola
fiscalcode fiscalCode
Basically, our webclient has a simple configuration:
public MultipartService() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder().build();      
}

spring-starter-webflux version is 2.2.2.RELEASE.
The question is: is there any way to erase the charset from contentType in webClient By means of strategies?
I've managed to accomplish the task by means of java RestRemplate this way:
@Service
public class MultipartService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${receiver.url}")
    private String receiverUrl;

    public MultipartService() {
       
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        MyFormHttpMessageConverter myFormHttpMessageConverter = new MyFormHttpMessageConverter();
        myFormHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));

        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = List.of(myFormHttpMessageConverter, stringHttpMessageConverter);
        this.restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMultipartData(PersonRequestDTO personRequest) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parts.add("name", personRequest.getNome());
        parts.add("surname", personRequest.getCognome());
        parts.add("fiscalCode", personRequest.getCodiceFiscale());

        //HTTP header without charset
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data"); 
      

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);
        return restTemplate.exchange(receiverUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    }

}

where MyFormHttpMessageConverter does the job.
Does anyone knows if there is an equivalent in webClient? I found nothing on the web...
Thanks for your help.
